# check Q Apply control table IBMQREP_RECVQUEUES

Tags: db2, ibm-mq

I am using Q Apply application to receive messages from an MQ Server and I am getting the following error message:

```
ASN0576E  "Q Apply" : "ASNQ" : "BR00000" : The program cannot access the    WebSphere MQ queue " ASN.COLDBBLD.ADMINQ". The queue name was specified in column "ADMINQ" of control table "IBMQREP_RECVQUEUES"
```

This ASN0576E code is when a queue doesn't exist or then the queue name is incorrect in the control tables. I already check the MQ side and everything is fine, the queue does exist, etc.. So the problem is on the DB2 side

I know I have to check in the IBMQREP_RECVQUEUES control table but I am not sure which command I should use. Is it asnqacmd, or asnqapp, etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your error message suggests the DB2 Config has a space on the front of the queue name.

Comment: Thanks you Morag as you suggested there was a space in front of the name. Can I use the SQL commands to alter the  IBMQREP_RECVQUEUES table?